# Ubuntu 14.04 not start after upgrade

Tags: 14.04

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 without any problems and then I gave the system update option. After all the packages were downloaded and stuff, I was asked to restart the system, but after that, it is not opening. I get a black screen shows

"error: file not found"
"grub rescue>"

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to repair grub?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/395045/how-to-repair-grub)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like something broke grub... Try booting from a live CD and doing a boot repair: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair