# Dual boot Ubuntu and Zorin

Tags: dual-boot, boot-repair

I had installed Zorin 16.1 on my laptop. I installed Ubuntu 20.04. Now, I cannot boot into Zorin because now `ubuntu` option on boot loader refer to Ubuntu os. In other word, Ubuntu and Zorin create the same directory in efi partition named `ubuntu`. When I installed Ubuntu the `ubuntu` directory was overridden by Ubuntu installer. How can I solve it?

Comment: Hello. The Zorin OS is off topic on this Ubuntu support site.

Comment: Hi @David, I think it is topic about ubuntu and zorin.

Comment: Does the new grub menu not detect Zorin?

Comment: Hi @ArchismanPanigrahi, yes, it doesn't detect Zorin.

Comment: Boot Ubuntu and run `sudo update-grub`. If Zoran is still there it should get added to Ubuntu's GRUB menu.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to repair grub?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/395045/how-to-repair-grub)

Comment: When ```Grub``` boots up what do you see? Several Ubuntu's ? Can you make a picture with your phone and add that to your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `etc/grub.d` you can modify your `10_linux_proxy file` ( you need to know in which partition you installed Zorin and in which partition you installed Ubuntu ).  To know the UUID use GParted. 
[image]. 
I changed `Ubuntu` into `Kubuntu` ( blue oval ), as well as (a part) of the submenu (added as 'Kubuntu blabla). I did the same in 30_os_prober_proxy. I changed `Ubuntu` in `Mint`. ( I run Kubuntu, Mint and Win10 ). You have to do this as Administrator. Always make backup first!! Then do a `sudo update-grub` in the `terminal`.
If you don't have a `10_linux_proxy`, but only a `10_linux` don't change that! Then you edit your `grub.cfg` directly. Don't do a `sudo update-grub` in the `terminal` then.